# Most concise way to express this Java conditional without checking a value twice

Tags: java, control-flow

I have a variable, `x`.

I want to call a method `m()` **only if** `x` is one of two possible values.

When calling `m()`, I want to pass an argument to it, whose value depends on the value of `x`.

Is there a way to do this in Java without checking the value of `x` more than once, and calling/writing `m()` in one place only (i.e. not in multiple branches of an `if` statement)?

One solution I'm entertaining:

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    y = "foo";
    break;
  case 2:
    y = "bar";
    break;
  default:
    y = null;
    break;
}

if (y != null) m(y);
```

But I can't help but feel this is *technically* checking `x` twice, just obscuring this fact by adding a "proxy" for the second check.

(To clarify why the constraints are what they are: when reading code, I have a hard time understanding logic that branches a lot when there is a high degree of duplication between branches - it becomes a game of "spot the difference" rather than simply being able to see what is happening. I prefer to aggressively refactor such duplication away, which is a habit that serves me well in Ruby, JS, and other languages; I'm hoping I can learn to do the same for Java and make code easier for me and others to understand at a glance.)

Comment: Create a `Map<Integer, String>` populate it with values for `1` and `2` and then use `map.get(x)` - no checks required.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is the Map a really better solution than just breaking his logic in two distinct `if` statement ? If it happens a lot I would understand but for small amount of this case is your solution really interesting ?

Comment: Your first example wouldn't work at all, it would have the same result for both 1 and 2.

Comment: ...You're absolutely right, @MarkoTopolnik.

Comment: How about wrapping y as an Optional, assigning empty to it rather than null, then mapping m onto it?

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with Optionals - could you write an example as an answer?

Comment: Why don't you want to do `switch (x) { case 1: m("foo"); break; case 2: m("bar"); break; }`  ? or use 2 `if` ? Do you have more than 2 cases in reality ?

Comment: Mostly just a preference thing. I dislike having e.g. multiple lines calling `m()` when the actual program flow means `m()` only gets called once. Naturally I can't stick to this preference religiously - sometimes it's not really viable - but when there's a high degree of repetition, I'd rather have there be a correspondence between how many times the characters `m()` appear in the file and how many times the function gets called at runtime.

Comment: Maybe you're being too dogmatic (no offense). Use @Jos solution if you really want to write a call to `m()` once.

Comment: I partly post this so that people can tell me when I'm being full of shit, so no offence taken. :)

Comment: @MadJlzz Is it really interesting with two cases, no. It is a way to do what OP asked, and I posted it as a comment because I didn't really have time to expand on [*the root of all evil*](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for the article, it makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "goto" or equivalent:

```
void do_m_if_appropriate() {

  // x and y are assumed to be eg. member variables

  switch (x) {

    case 1:
      y = "foo";
      break;

    case 2:
      y = "bar";
      break;

    default:
      return; // this is the "goto equivalent" part
  }

  m(y);
}
```

Above is pretty elegant. If necessary, it's also trivial to change it to return `true` or `false` depending on if it called `m()`, or just `y` or `null`.

---

You can also do tricks with loop constructs, though some might say this is abuse of the loop construct, and you should comment it accordingly:

```
do { // note: not a real loop, used to skip call to m()
  switch (x) {

    case 1:
      y = "foo";
      break;

    case 2:
      y = "bar";
      break;

    default:
      continue; // "goto equivalent" part
  }

  m(y);
} while(false);
```

Comment: Oooh, cute. You're using the surrounding scope as a flow control tool, and then using the continuation of the block to imply "an appropriate value is found".

Comment: Accepting this answer for the time being as it is the least weird, using only tools that exist in most common languages, while meeting all the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of what you want to do, but you can maybe use a Map to get the 'y' parameter from 'x'

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "foo");
map.put(2, "bar");

if (map.containsKey(x)) {
    m(map.get(x));
}
```

Comment: The Ruby developer in me loves this.

Comment: Glad to see you like this ;) Maps can sometimes be very efficient to solve problems

Comment: @Jos I wouldn't call this efficient by any means... Concise or terse, sure, possibly even elegant, but not efficient.

Comment: @hyde humm I don't think the map is less efficient than the switch case. Prove me I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jos Well, for starters, with a map the key needs to be boxed. Also this is kinda checking `x` twice, which seems to contradict what OP requests in their question text.

Comment: You could even use `map.getOrDefault(x, "default")` (if such a default value exists for the OP) to get rid of the `if`.

Comment: Or `Optional.ofNullable(map.get(x)).ifPresent(y -> m(y));`

Comment: @4castle nice, or even nicer IMHO with a method reference instead of a lambda: `Optional.ofNullable(map.get(x)).ifPresent(this::m);` or IMHO nicer still with all method references: `Optional.of(x).map(map::get).ifPresent(this::m);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with Optionals (my Java syntax might be slightly incorrect). Note that to you, the code looks like so, but implementation wise, it's similar to the example you posted (i.e. checks whether y is an exceptional value).

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    y = Optional<String>.of("foo");
    break;
  case 2:
    y = Optional<String>.of("bar");
    break;
  default:
    y = Optional<String>.empty();
    break;
}
y.map((m's class)::m);
result = y.orElse( <value result should take if x was invalid> );
```

Actually it may be better to modify m() to return an Optional and just return empty if y is not valid, but I assume you want to do this check caller-side.

Answer (score -1):

Why not

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    y = "foo";
    m(y);
    break;
  case 2:
    y = "bar";
    m(y);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Like I say in the post: I don't want to call `m()` in more than one place, as you have done.

Comment: My bad, I thought you had meant you only wanted to call it once (not necessarily have it one place in the code).